# appstore submit failed

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I tried to submit app to app store recently and failed while reviewing.
Here's the message from app store.
I updated 5.5-inch iPhone screenshots with 1242*2208 but same issue comes.
How to solve this issue?
I uploaded 3 screenshots for 5.5-inch and 12.9-inch(2nd-generation).

> Guideline 2.3.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata
>
> We noticed that your screenshots do not sufficiently reflect your app
>   in use.
>
> Specifically, your 5.5-inch iPhone screenshots include iPhone XS
>   display features.

[image]

Comment: The message from Apple seems clear.

Comment: can you please explain me more about that?
So what I have to change?

Comment: your screenshot contains "notch" display ?

Comment: @AntonEgorovich can you just show us your uploaded screenshots ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha, I uploaded screenshot.
Please have a look and let me know your idea.

Comment: 5.5 inch design is for 6s plus, 7 plus, 8 plus. that device not have notch display. The time display in center of status bar. in your screenshot, you have time in left hand side which is like iPhone X, XS latest display (notch) screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen your screenshot and apple is right. your screenshot contains iPhone XS Features.

5.5 inch design is for 6 Plus, 6s plus, 7 plus, 8 plus. that device not have notch display. **The time display in center of status bar**. in your screenshot, you have time in left hand side which is like iPhone XS screen.

I have attached screenshot for your reference. please check it.

[image]

Comment: run your app in iphone 6 plus or 6s plus or 7 plus or 8 plus and take screenshot then upload it. apple will not reject it.

Comment: It worked. Thanks,
And now I got another issue.
Could you please help with this?

Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

Your app or its metadata does not appear to include final content. 
Specifically, your application description does not reflect the functionality of your application.

Comment: You have to change your description as per your apps functionality.

Comment: After change your description (in itunes connect --> my apps --> select your app --> description) submit app again. If it's metadata rejected then no need to upload build again. If it's binary rejected then you have to upload new build.

Comment: so all this related to only description?

Comment: Yes, as per your message it's only for description.

Comment: Hi, @NiravKotecha
I resubmitted but failed again. I will try one more time and let you know the result.
Thanks.

Comment: @AntonEgorovich again failed with same reason of description or other.

Comment: I successfully submitted to App Store, Many Thanks, @NiravKotecha

Comment: @AntonEgorovich okay great.